# How to filter using regex in Google Cloud Compute node.js getVMs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In the Google Cloud Compute library for Node JS, how can I filter using regex with `options.filter` within the `getVMs` method?

Docs: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/compute/0.7.1/compute?method=getVMs

My attempt below returns an empty array, and there's no clear example in the docs (yet!). My goal is to get the one instance that start with "prefix" as its name.

There are 101 instances, and this is the 101st.

```
compute.getVMs({
    maxResults: 100,
    filter: 'name eq ^prefix'
});
```

> Search filter in the format of {name} {comparison} {filterString}.
>   name: the name of the field to compare
>   comparison: the comparison operator, eq (equal) or ne (not equal)
>   filterString: the string to filter to. **For string fields, this can be a regular expression**.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ".*$" at the end of your pattern. Basically you need to specify you want to "match a string starting with 'prefix', followed by any number of characters after the 'prefix' until the end of the whole string". You can suppress the 'end of the whole string' special char ($) but you cannot suppress the 'match any number of characters' special chars (.*). Here is a working example:

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const gce = new Compute({
  projectId: 'your-project-id-here'
});

gce.getVMs({
    maxResults: 100,
    filter: 'name eq ^prefix.*'
}, function(err, vms) {
  console.log(vms);
});
```

Comment: How can you filter by multiple labels or tags?? I can do it by one label like so getVMs({"filter":"labels.env=devops}) but when I try with {"filter":"labels.env=devops,labels.type=tomcat"} it doesnt work any ideas?

Comment: @yokodev instead of a comma try `OR` or `AND`. eg. `labels.env=devops AND labels.type=tomcat`. If its not that it could be `||` (OR) or `&&` (AND).